# Spurious, incorrect notification of previously awarded mortarboard

Tags: bug, badges, achievements-dialog

Well, I got a surprise in my notification inbox just now.... apparently I was just awarded a mortarboard on PCG (Code Golf).... except, I have had no reputation on that site for a while, and I was awarded that badge a couple of years ago...

This is what my notifications currently look like:

[image: Mortarboard]

This is obviously some sort of notification bug, but I have no idea of what to blame..... it's probably too long to blame caching.... given that it's two years too late.

Comment: I sometimes see notifications for messages I received days ago, which I had already clicked on, read, and even gone back to later to re-read. I think there's a gremlin somewhere in the system (possibly the DB Table which stores "has been read")