# Badges awarded out of their time and seemingly without cause

Tags: bug, review, badges

There's a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267327/spurious-incorrect-notification-of-previously-awarded-mortarboard) from nearly six years ago, but without any answers.

Just now, on [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour), I was awarded the [Steward badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188732#188732) for completing 1,000 review tasks (close votes):

[image]

You'll of course notice that I've completed in excess of 1,300 reviews of this type, hitting the 1,000 mark perhaps a year or so ago.

The same goes for the one on *[English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour)* for new posts, which was also completed (probably) more than a year ago.

Are we buggy about badges at the moment, or does someone "up there" like me?